# Why does my if-else statements drip over towards the third else?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to get an idea of how this control syntax works.

Note: this is part of my `int.main` function:

```
while(cin >> Options){
    if(Options == 1){ //If I enter '1' here it will output: "aHi.Else."
        cout << "a";
    }else{
        cout << "hi";
    }
    if(Options == 2){ //If I enter '2' here it will output: "hiaElse."
        cout << "a";
    }else{
        cout <<"Hi.";
    }
    if(Options == 3){ //If I enter '3' here it will output: "hiHi.a"
        cout << "a";
    }else{
        cout << "Else." << endl;
    }
}
```

Why is it dripping over to `else's` and stuff? What's wrong with the syntax? I'm confused?
How am I supposed to use multiple `if` statements without `else's` included? Can you give an example?

Comment: What do you expect this to be doing, and why?

Comment: Use a `switch` statement; or a table lookup.

Comment: You could use a `switch` statement or change all your `else` to `else if (condition)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ifs` are not dependent on each other, so if `Options` is anything but 1, it will execute the else branch of the first `if` statement, even if Options is 2 or 3. The same applies to the other ifs. Since `Options` can only be 1 or 2 or 3 (or something else), you will always get the `else` output for the other `if`s.

You can chain `else` and `if` if you want to link multiple conditions to each other. In the example below, the last `else` only executes if `Options` is neither 1, nor 2, nor 3.

```
while(cin >> Options){
    if(Options == 1){
        cout << "a";
    }
    else if(Options == 2){
        cout << "b";
    }
    else if(Options == 3){
        cout << "c";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Hello";
    }
}
```

or using a `switch` statement:

```
while(cin >> Options){
    switch(Options){
      case 1:
        cout << "a";
        break;
      case 2:
        cout << "b";
        break;
      case 3: 
        cout << "c";
        break;
      default:
        cout << "Hello";
    }
}
```